# Get selectedItem data value from Treeview in actionscript flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, treeview

Main Thread (Suspended: ReferenceError: Error #1081: Property @data not found on Object and there is no default value.)

Hi All i am getting the above error when calling:

private function openStrm(event:Event):void {

```
            if (event) {
                getThingsInStrm(event.currentTarget.selectedItem.@data);
            }               
        }
```

There is definitely a data property in the selectedItem i can see it in the watch/Variables window while debugging. I am not an as developer so i am a bit lost. Any help is appreciated! thanks

Comment: Hi Todd, if you just see event.currentTarget.selectedItem has a data property and selectedItem isn't typed as XML (you'll see the type in the variables/watch pane) then you need to just drop the @ symbol, that's used for getting XML attributes.  Otherwise posting a screenshot of what you see in there will probably help get you a solution quicker.

Comment: Thanks you are right. I was binding an ArrayCollection and not XML. If i directly reference it without the @ it works! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The selectedItem is usually an object form your dataProvider.  Does that object contain a property named data?

Show us your actual data, and perhaps a runnable sample and maybe we can help more.